# ¿por que no sale del bucle for?

Tags: java, bucle-for, bluej

Digitar numeros hasta que se introduzca uno negativo, luego mostrar la cantidad de numeros negativos tecleados

```
public class bucles4{
 public static void main(String[]args){
    int numero, contador;
    contador = 0;
    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
    boolean condicion = numero >= 0;
    
    for(int i= 0; condicion; i++){
        
        contador = i;
      
        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));
    }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has tecleado: "+contador+"  cantidad de numeros");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yo te recomendaría que usar un while de ves un for

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que dentro del `for` ya no estas evaluando si el numero introducido es negativo, agrega ahì tambien esta evaluacion, de esta forma podra salir del bucle:

```
public class bucles4{
 public static void main(String[]args){
    int numero, contador;
    contador = 0;
    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
    boolean condicion = numero >= 0;
    
    for(int i= 0; condicion; i++){
        
        contador++;
      
        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));

        //*Evalua si es negativo.
        condicion = numero >= 0;

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has tecleado: "+contador+"  cantidad de numeros");
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que desde un inicio declaraste la variable condición antes del for y esta variable evalua si se cumple o no y como desde un inicio si se cumple nunca sale del ciclo lo unico que falta es volverla a asignar en el for de la siguiente manera:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
   int numero, contador;
    contador = 0;
    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un numero"));
    boolean v = numero>=0;
    
    for(int i= 1 ; v ; i++){
       
        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite otro numero"));
        contador = i;
        v = numero >=0;
        
    }
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has tecleado: "+contador+"  cantidad de numeros");
    
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  // importa librería javax.swing para usar JOptionPane.
public class Bucles{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        // necesitas decir primero cuantos números vas a introducir para que ese número
        // sea el límite del bucle o for loop. Con for loop no puedes hacer bucles
        // indefinidamente. Eso lo hace un while o do while loop, entonces......

        int contador;
        contador = 0;

        String cantidad_de_numeros; // variable string.
        cantidad_de_numeros = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuántos números ingresarás?"); // pide entrar la cantidad de números a ser entrados.
        int cuantosnumeros = Integer.parseInt(cantidad_de_numeros); // variable cuantosnumeros parse a int el valor del string cantidad_de_numeros.

        for(int i= 0; i < cuantosnumeros; i++)
        {
            String numero; // variable string
            numero = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un número:"); // pide entrar uno o varios números
            int numero_entrado = Integer.parseInt(numero); // variable numero_entrado parse a int el valor del string numero
                
            contador++; //contador, en caso de que se quiera contar el número negativo.

            if (numero_entrado < 0) //evalua si número es negativo
            {
                break; //si es negativo sale del bucle o for loop y salta a imprimir la cantidad de números entrados.
            }
    
            //contador++; //contador, en caso de que no se quiera contabilizar el número negativo.
        }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Usuario ha entrado " + contador + " número(s)"); // muestra cantidad de números entrados
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

boolean solo maneja estados true o false. no puedes asignarle un valor que no sea true o false

la declaracion de for es:
for (int i = 0; i < variableConValorNumerico_o_Array; i++) {/* tu codigo */}

Comment: Él no esta asignando, está comparando que la variable numero sea mayor o igual a 0 y el resultado retornara true  o false